# An image conveyor belt in CSS?

Tags: css, animation, slideshow

I've been racking my brain on whether it's possible to have a div show a never-ending "conveyor belt" pattern that always goes in one direction.

You can take a div, tile a background image in one direction with repeat-x, then create a keyframe that moves the background-position by the width of one tile, which will bring the background to the same position where it was at the beginning of the transition.

What I can't figure out is how to "reset" the background-position, so that the cycle can run once again and create the illusion of continuous single-direction motion. Can this be done in CSS?

I could animate a gif and fake it that way, but they are rather large/slow to load & there is always a stutter during the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found something relevant on a website, after a brief search.

**Sprites file:**

[image: sprites file]

**Fiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/8676/

**Browser support:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hi"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");

    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's just the thing! If I apply this keyframe animation to a tiling background, I do get the continuous "belt" effect. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user3908964 glad it helps. You should upvote/accept the answer btw.